# Is "in the cloud" gsutil cp an atomic operation?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Assuming I have copied one object into a Google Cloud Storage bucket using the following command:

```
gsutil -h "Cache-Control:public,max-age=3600" cp -a public-read a.html gs://some-bucket/
```

I now want to copy this file "in the cloud" while keeping the public ACL and simultaneously updating the Cache-Control header:

```
gsutil -h "Cache-Control:no-store" cp -p gs://some-bucket/a.html gs://some-bucket/b.html
```

Is this operation atomic? I.e. can I be sure, that the object `gs://some-bucket/b.html` will become initially available with the modified `Cache-Control:no-store` header?

The reason for my question is: I'm using a Google Cloud Storage bucket as a CDN-backend. While I want most of the objects in the bucket to be cached by the CDN according to the `max-age` provided in the `Cache-Control` header I want to make sure that a few specific files, which are in fact copies of cacheable versions, are *never* cached by a CDN. It is therefore crucial that these objects – when being copied – never appear with a `Cache-Control:public,max-age=XXX` but immediately appear with a `Cache-Control:no-store` header as to eliminate the chance that a request coming from a CDN would read the copied object at a point in time where a `max-age` would still be present and hence cache the object which is supposed to never be cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, copying to the new object with Cache-Control set will be atomic. You can verify this by looking at the metageneration property of the object.

For example, upload an object:

```
$ BUCKET=mybucket
$ echo foo | ./gsutil cp - gs://$BUCKET/foo.txt
Copying from <STDIN>...
/ [1 files][    0.0 B/    0.0 B]                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects.
```

and you'll see that its initial metageneration is 1:

```
$ ./gsutil ls -L gs://$BUCKET/foo.txt | grep Meta
    Metageneration:         1
```

Whenever an object's metadata is modified, the metageneration is changed. For example, if the cache control is updated later like so:

```
$ ./gsutil setmeta -h "Cache-Control:no-store" gs://$BUCKET/foo.txt
Setting metadata on gs://mybucket/foo.txt...
/ [1 objects]                                                                   
Operation completed over 1 objects.
```

The new metageneration is 2:

```
$ ./gsutil ls -L gs://$BUCKET/foo.txt | grep Meta
    Metageneration:         2
```

Now, if we run the copy command:

```
$ ./gsutil -h "Cache-Control:no-store" cp -p gs://$BUCKET/foo.txt gs://$BUCKET/bar.txt
Copying gs://mybucket/foo.txt [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
- [1 files][    4.0 B/    4.0 B]                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects/4.0 B.
```

The metageneration of the new object is 1:

```
$ ./gsutil ls -L gs://$BUCKET/bar.txt | grep Meta
    Metageneration:         1
```

This means that the object was written once and has not been modified since.